service mysql restart sometimes sends ubuntu load average to over 200, and it doesn't go down
I have an app that seems to grab excess mysql connections (8.0.40-0ubuntu0.24.04.1),
to reset i use "service mysql restart", but one time in 10 the processor load average going above 200 and won't go down. How to fix this? Is it a bug in the mysql server?

'Load' is not actual CPU load, but the number of processes in 'runnable' state, which could also mean IO. Do you have stats or graphs server resources? It's probably not a bug in MySQL. It could be that it's out of RAM, or hanging IO because the storage is breaking down, etc. When looking at htop, press F2 and enable 'detailed cpu stats'. Then you can see also see IOWAIT, which can sometimes be 100% CPU on all cores. It's not actual CPU time. Read up on what it means.

From experience, the excessive CPU Load typically suggests that either the machine itself needs more Memory and/or MySQL needs additional memory allocated.
Since the first option is more or less self-explanatory, to accomplish the second option, you will have to Open your "my.cnf" MySQL Configuration File (normally under "/etc/my.cnf", in Linux/Unix OSes) and Update the following Settings, etc.

innodb_buffer_pool_size
key_buffer
query_cache_size
query_cache_limit
thread_cache_size
max_connections
innodb_lock_wait_timeout

For additional information, you may want to review the following discussion.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709169/2649063

I will try it and update the question weather it fixed the problem

High CPU (or Load Average) comes from multiple simultaneously long-running queries.  Use the SlowLog to discover which queries are involved.  Then work on making them more efficient:

Carefully selected composite indexes
Post some of the queries here, together with SHOW CREATE TABLEs and EXPLAIN SELECT ... for help from us.

